# How to make a Graph without using classes in Python

Tags: python-3.x, graph, weighted-graph

This might seem like an odd question, but I have a project for school, to make a weighted unordered graph but without using classes or numpy. Can anyone give me some advice on how to start?

```
from collections import defaultdict 
   
#This class represents a directed graph using adjacency list representation 
class Graph: 
   
    def __init__(self,vertices): 
        self.V = vertices #No. of vertices 
        self.V_org = vertices 
        self.graph = defaultdict(list) # default dictionary to store graph 
   
    # function to add an edge to graph 
    def addEdge(self,u,v,w): 
        if w == 1: 
            self.graph[u].append(v) 
        else:     
            self.graph[u].append(self.V) 
            self.graph[self.V].append(v) 
            self.V = self.V + 1
      
    # To print the shortest path stored in parent[] 
    def printPath(self, parent, j): 
        Path_len = 1
        if parent[j] == -1 and j < self.V_org : #Base Case : If j is source 
            print (j)
            return 0 # when parent[-1] then path length = 0     
        l = self.printPath(parent , parent[j]) 
  
 
        Path_len = l + Path_len 
        if j < self.V_org :  
            print (j)
  
        return Path_len 

    def findShortestPath(self,src, dest): 
  
        visited =[False]*(self.V) 
        parent =[-1]*(self.V) 
   
        # Create a queue for BFS 
        queue=[] 
   
        # Mark the source node as visited and enqueue it 
        queue.append(src) 
        visited[src] = True
   
        while queue : 
              
            # Dequeue a vertex from queue  
            s = queue.pop(0) 
              
            # if s = dest then print the path and return 
            if s == dest: 
                return self.printPath(parent, s) 
                 
            for i in self.graph[s]: 
                if visited[i] == False: 
                    queue.append(i) 
                    visited[i] = True
                    parent[i] = s
```

This is what I made using classes.
If the question is not related to this forum I will delete it.
Also I am not that experimented with python, I mostly write in C++ so I am not sure if python has **struct** or I was thinking of using a vector of pairs to store first vertex, second vertex and the weight.

Comment: If it is only the storing of the graph you can use an [adjeceny list](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/graph-adjacency-list). Where the values in the list are represented by the goal node and the goal weight.

Comment: @Thymen Well I have to do several more operations like computing the shortest distance, check if the graph is connected, check if the graph has cycles. Can I do all of these things using adjacency list?

Comment: Yes all of the above operations can be done using adjacency lists. But the part of not using Classes is kinda weird if I look at your code, you can directly remove the class and use the methods as functions instead. The only thing is that you will probably have to use a global variable to add edges to your graph variable.